# Bigcommerce product image snippet in custom panel

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm new to Bigcommerce and hoping someone can help me figure out if I'm doing anything wrong here. I'm simply trying to create a custom template for my product pages. I created a new file called "_product.html", uploaded it via FTP, and applied it to one of my products.

Within this file I have a default panel called ProductDetails.html. This panel makes a reference to the products thumbnail images. Everything works as expected.

However, I now copy the content from the ProductDetails.html panel and place it in a new panel called ProductInformation.html. At this point, there is no difference between ProductDetails.html and ProductInformation.html, except for the name.

I then go into my _product.html template and replace the reference to the ProductDetails panel with a reference to my new ProductInformation panel. Now, none of the snippets or global variables are being populated. They print nothing to the page.

If I put the original reference to the ProductDetails panel back, everything is displayed as expected. Is there something I'm missing here? Are the snippets and global variables used in the system-created ProductDetails panel only available in that file and not available to other custom panels created for a product page?

I really appreciate any help you can provide! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, there is a key element inside of the ProductDetails Panel that is needed to get all the variables to work on a product page. I think the order even matters.
I would recommend using Snippets to control the information you want to swap out on a custom product page.

Answer (score 0):

The ProductDetails panel populates the global variables that you are trying to use. If you do not have it on the custom page then you cannot use the variables inside of it. The workaround is to place the panel inside an HTML comment:

```
<!-- %%Panel.ProductDetails%% -->
```

That way the panel will be called by the Bigcommerce template system without affecting the rest of your layout.